# How can I have Python TTK use the Windows OS default progress bar theme?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter

How in TTK can I use the OS default loader theme instead of the tkinter one?

[image: Loading - Known]

[image: Loading - Unknown]

This is an example of a normal progress bar.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x250+1000+300')

progress_bar = Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=100, mode='indeterminate')
progress_bar.pack(expand=True)
progress_bar.start()

root.mainloop()
```

I get a progress bar, but it isn't themed like the OS default progress bar is.

[image: TTK-themed progress bar]

I thought that perhaps a style could make it look like that, so I listed the styles:

```py
Style().theme_names() # ('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')
```

I tried each one like so:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x250+1000+300')

os_default_style = Style()
os_default_style.theme_use('THEME')
os_default_style.configure('osdefault.Horizontal.TProgressbar')
progress_bar = Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=100, mode='indeterminate', style='osdefault.Horizontal.TProgressbar')
progress_bar.pack(expand=True)
progress_bar.start()

root.mainloop()
```

They produce ones that are similar, but none are the system.  How do I make it look exactly like one used by the system?

Comment: where do you want to load it?

Comment: onto the class 'setup' (a tkinter.Tk object)

Comment: Could we use `ttk.Style` for `progressbar`?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA If it gets the OS native look, yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, a 'truly native' widget is not possible in Tk. As you can see in the [source](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/library/ttk/xpTheme.tcl), a theme simply sets a bunch of settings and it does not do anything you couldn't do yourself. However, finding a good theme will generally do a 'good enough' job (see [ASI's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67753610/7496549) for more details on this).

If you don't believe me, take a look at the `ProgressbarDoLayout` method (and related methods - [found here](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/generic/ttk/ttkProgress.c)) and you can see that Tk is handling the drawing itself and giving very little to the native software.

Answer (score 4):

I think is a little bit case  sensitive the "default OS theme"... **xpnative** is the close to the native one and almost fool the eyes. I created an test to see the differences (note I use windows 7) and the result for default OS style reveal like **xpnative** is the winner. **vista** look same but is a little bigger that is all. Now if OS use simple theme, this two will not work, but other will do... For windows 10, classic tkinter theme is close to this OS theme, but tkinter.ttk will do same thing on windows 10... Is to sensitive this subject. Just on windows are some obstacles, I even do not mentioned Linux... Theme is not so important, if your project is making the job right and is close enough to default theme of the user OS from my view point is more than perfect.

Here is my test:

```py
# Import
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# Logic
class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        # Create the progress bar
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.master, value=0)
        self.progress.pack(expand=False, fill="x", side="top", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.progress.start()

        # Create two layers for the theme
        self.default = self.Layer("Default")    # for default foundet ones
        self.custom = self.Layer("Custom")      # for manual input and debug purpose

        # Create the entry and applay elements for the "custom layer"
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self.custom)
        ttk.Button(self.custom, text="Apply...", width=15, command=lambda:self.ChangeTheme(self.entry.get().strip())
                   ).pack(side="right")
        self.entry.pack(expand=True, fill="x", side="left")

        # Get a list of all default themes and create a button for each one
        for theme in ttk.Style().theme_names(): self.ThemeDefault(theme)

    def ThemeDefault(self, themeName:str) -> None:
        ttk.Button(self.default, text=themeName, width=15, command=lambda:self.ChangeTheme(themeName)).pack(side="left")

    def Layer(self, text:str) -> tk.Frame:
        frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=text, width=7, anchor="w")
        frame.pack(expand=False, fill="x", side="top", padx=5, pady=5)
        label.pack(side="left")
        return frame

    def ChangeTheme(self, themeName:str) -> None:
        try: ttk.Style(self.master).theme_use(themeName)
        except Exception as e: print(f">> EXCEPTION // {e}")

# Run if this file is the main opened one
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is what is look like the resoult.
[image]

Comment: On Windows 10, Vista is similar, but with some key differences: the color is off, the "animated stripe" (open a loader in Windows 10 and you'll see what I mean) is missing, and it's slightly short.  While these are subtle, this is an indication that it is not using the native loader, but rather a similar-looking theme.

Comment: Is a good and a bad part here. is bad because is not using like default OS theme settings, is simulate, but the good part is that you can create your own theme style or to use some others [examples](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes)

Comment: @ASI On this line: `def Layer(self, text:str) -> object`, wouldn't it be better to use `tk.Frame` instead of `object` for the return type annotation?

Comment: Yes it is @TheLizzard . I use `object` to define return state of anything else than `None`, `int`, `str`... My style is not perfect yet, I still learn programming like a hobby. Thanks for the suggestion. I think this will impact a better image of what is returning.

Comment: @ASI I only recently started using that kind of annotations. So I am still learning how to use it properly. Given your programming skills, I would have never guessed that this is just a hobby for you :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('winnative')
s.configure("Blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar", foreground='white',
            background='blue')
P1 = ttk.Progressbar(root, style="Blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar",
                     orient="horizontal", length=600, mode="indeterminate",
                     maximum=4, value=1)
P1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using `P1 = ttk.Progressbar(...).pack()` is highly discouraged. The reason is that whatever `.pack()` returns (always `None`) will be stored in `P1` and not the `ttk.Progressbar` object.